# Converting string to nested map in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

I have a file containing some text like:

```
1|apple|sweet
2|coffee|bitter
3|gitpush|relief
```

I want to work with this input using a map. In Java or Python, I would have made a nested map like:

```
{1: {thing: apple, taste: sweet},
2: {thing: coffee, taste: bitter},
3: {thing: gitpush, taste: relief}}
```

Or even a list inside the map like:

```
{1: [apple, sweet],
2: [coffee, bitter],
3: [grape, sour]}
```

The end goal is to access the last two column's data efficiently using the first column as the key.
I want to do this in Clojure and I am new to it. So far, I have succeeded in creating a list of map using the following code:

```
(def cust_map (map (fn [[id name taste]] 
       (hash-map :id (Integer/parseInt id)
                 :name name 
                 :taste taste ))
     (map #(str/split % #"\|") (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader path)))))
```

And I get this, but it's not what I want.

```
({1, apple, sweet},
{2, coffee, bitter},
{3, gitpush, relief})
```

It would be nice if you can show me how to do the most efficient of, or both nested map and list inside map in Clojure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build a map with [`hash-map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/hash-map), the arguments are alternative keys and values. For example:

```
(hash-map :a 0 :b 1)
=> {:b 1, :a 0}
```

From what I understand, you want to have a unique key, the integer, which maps to a compound object, a map:

```
(hash-map 0 {:thing "apple" :taste "sweet"})
```

Also, you do not want to call `map`, which would result in a sequence of maps. You want to have a single hash-map being built.
Try using [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(reduce (fn [map [id name taste]]
          (merge map
                 (hash-map (Integer/parseInt id)
                           {:name name :taste taste})))
        {}
        '(("1" "b" "c")
          ("2" "d" "e")))
```

--- edit

Here is the full test program:

```
(import '(java.io BufferedReader StringReader))

(def test-input (line-seq
                 (BufferedReader.
                  (StringReader.
                   "1|John Smith|123 Here Street|456-4567
2|Sue Jones|43 Rose Court Street|345-7867
3|Fan Yuhong|165 Happy Lane|345-4533"))))

(def a-map
  (reduce
   (fn [map [id name address phone]]
     (merge map
            (hash-map (Integer/parseInt id)
                      {:name name :address address :phone phone})))
   {}
   (map #(clojure.string/split % #"\|") test-input)))

a-map
=> {1 {:name "John Smith", :address "123 Here Street", :phone "456-4567"}, 2 {:name "Sue Jones", :address "43 Rose Court Street", :phone "345-7867"}, 3 {:name "Fan Yuhong", :address "165 Happy Lane", :phone "345-4533"}}
```

Comment: You have understood the problem correctly. But, I am not clear with your solution (empty braces). And I am getting "clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector" with this solution. Please refer: https://pastebin.com/xN01bZtg

Comment: In your pastebin, you have `((reduce ...))`, ie. too many enclosing parentheses. The empty braces is the initial value of the hash-map when using reduce.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @coredump that this is not concise, yet a quick solution to your code is using a list (or any other collection) and a nested map:

```
(def cust_map (map (fn [[id name taste]] 
       (list (Integer/parseInt id)
                 (hash-map :name name 
                           :taste taste)))
     (map #(clojure.string/split % #"\|") (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader path)))))
```

Comment: Using a list as a container for the maps will not be very beneficial because I cannot access each inner map by key. Anything suggestion ?

Comment: it can be a vector or anything. This is just a demonstration of the correct syntax in the particular case. You can access the elements of the list with `nth` and the elements in the nested map with the respected keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a somewhat naive view on my part, as I'm not all that experienced with Clojure, but any time I want to make a map from a collection I immediately think of `zipmap`:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io :refer [reader]])

(defn lines-from [fname]
  (line-seq (io/reader fname)))

(defn nested-map [fname re keys]
  "fname : full path and filename to the input file
   re    : regular expression used to split file lines into columns
   keys  : sequence of keys for the trailing columns in each line. The first column
           of each line is assumed to be the line ID"
  (let [lines       (lines-from fname)
        line-cols   (map #(clojure.string/split % re) lines)      ; (["1" "apple" "sweet"] ["2" "coffee" "bitter"] ["3" "gitpush" "relief"])
        ids         (map #(Integer/parseInt (first %)) line-cols) ; (1 2 3)
        rest-cols   (map rest line-cols)                          ; (("apple" "sweet") ("coffee" "bitter") ("gitpush" "relief"))
        rest-maps   (map #(zipmap keys %) rest-cols)]             ; ({:thing "apple", :taste "sweet"} {:thing "coffee", :taste "bitter"} {:thing "gitpush", :taste "relief"})
    (zipmap ids rest-maps)))

(nested-map "C:/Users/whatever/q50663848.txt" #"\|" [:thing :taste])
```

produces

```
{1 {:thing "apple", :taste "sweet"}, 2 {:thing "coffee", :taste "bitter"}, 3 {:thing "gitpush", :taste "relief"}}
```

I've shown the intermediate results of each step in the `let` block as a comment so you can see what's going on. I've also tossed in `lines-from`, which is just my thin wrapper around `line-seq` to keep myself from having to type in `BufferedReader.` and `StringReader.` all the time. :-)

Comment: If you require `clojure.java.io`, you can get the line seq with just `(line-seq (io/reader fname))`.

Comment: @glts - good point - and you can do away entirely with the `require` by using `(line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader fname))`. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Cheers, Bob. You shouldn’t really get rid of the `require` though: if it works without that `require` then that would be a hidden side effect of some of the existing dependencies (currently) depending on `clojure.java.io`. Also, it’s good to be explicit about the namespaces depended on.

Comment: @glts - OK - added `require` to pull in `reader` from clojure.java.io.